# How to check if a string is certain amount of characters and contains (or doesn't contain) certain characters? C++

Tags: c++, string, input, error-handling, boolean

Let's say I have two strings (string1, string2) based off of user inputs. I want  **string1** to be **at least 5 characters**, **at most 10 characters**, and only allowed to contain the following:

1. Upper case letters
2. Lower case letters
3. Numbers (0-9)

Otherwise, the user will be prompted to keep entering strings until the requirements are met.

```
while(len(string1)<5 or len(string1)>10) {
    if(len(string1) > 10) {
        cout << "Please enter a string that is less than 10 characters: ";
        cin >> input;
    } else if(len(string) < 5) {
        cout << "Please enter a string that is more than 5 characters: ";
        cin >> input;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a string with legal characters (uppercase/lowercase letters and numbers): ";
        cin >> input;
    }
```

How would I check if string1 only contains uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and numbers? Would I use the following in some sort of way?...

```
string legalChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";   
string1.find_first_not_of(legalChars)
```

As for string2, I want the user input to be **at least 6 characters long** and to contain **at least one non-letter character**.

```
while(len(string2)<6) {
    if(len(string2)<6) {
        cout << "Please enter a string that is at least 6 characters long: ";
        cin >> input2;
    } 
}
```

How would I check for non-letter characters in string2? How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Except that `len(string1)` is `string1.length()` so - yes. If you succeed in checking that one string is letters and digits only, it must be very simple to check that the other string is not. It's the same test, but with the opposite result.

Comment: Well, if you only have to support English... :)

Answer (score 1):

For `string1` you can simply check for the length to be at least 5 characters and at most 10 characters (use [`std::string::length`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/)), and pass each character into [`isalnum`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalnum/) to check if it is alphanumeric.

For `string2` you can check that it's at least 6 characters long and has at least one uppercase letter by using [`isupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/).

Or as @Lorehead pointed out, you can just use regex. Which is better is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::regex_match()`. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). No complete answer because this sounds like homework.

If you have to do it the old-fashioned way, you can use the functions `isalnum()` from `<ctype.h>` and `strspn()` from `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your Question.......
Here is the link to ascii chart [ASCII Chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
     string input1,input2;
     bool inpFlag1=false,inpFlag2=false;

     while(inpFlag1 == false)
     {
             cout<<"Enter First String:"<<endl;
             cin>>input1;

           if(input1.size()<4 || input1.size()>10)
           {
             cout<<"Error!Min:5 Characters and Max:10 characters!"<<endl;
           }
           else
           {
            for(int i=0;i<input1.size();i++)
            {
            if((input1.at(i)>= 48 && input1.at(i)<=57) ||(input1.at(i)>=65 && input1.at(i)<=90) || (input1.at(i)>=97 && input1.at(i)<= 122 )) 
            {
              continue;
            }
            else
            {
             cout<<"Error Input string does not match conditions!"<<endl;
             inpFlag1=false;
             break;
            }
           }
          inpFlag1=true;
      }
     }

   while(inpFlag2 == false)
   {
     cout<<"Enter Second String:"<<endl;
     cin>>input2;

     if(input2.size()<6)
     {
      cout<<"Error! String should contain Min:6 Characters"<<endl;
     }
     else
     {
       for(int i=0;i<input2.size();i++)
       {
         if(input2.at(i)>=33 && input2.at(i)<=126)
         {
          continue;
         }
         else
         {
          cout<<"Error Input String does not match required conditions!" <<endl;
          inpFlag2=false;
          break;
         }
       }
       inpFlag2=true; 
      }
   }
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"Entered Strings:"<<endl;
   cout<<input1<<endl;
   cout<<input2<<endl;


   return 0;
  }
```